# Retriving Account Information of available Contacts

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a list of Contact Id in 'c1' parameter. I want to display the Account and contact information using parent-child relationship.

apex code:

```
for(Contact c2:c1)
{

    acc = [select name from Account where Id IN (select name from Contact where Id =:c2.Id) ];
    system.debug('acc values-->'+ acc);

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide mode information about your needs and the problem you're facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all get the SOQL query out of the for loop. You can build a set or a list of ids of Contacts.

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
//Loop and add the various ids to the set

List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Id In (Select AccountId From Contact Where Id =: contactIds ]
```

Or if you have selected the AccountId, instead of adding the ids of the contacts to the Set, you can add the AccountId and your SOQL query will be like this:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
//loop through the contacts and add the ids

List<Account> accounts = [Select Name From Accounts Where Id = :accountIds];
```